# Tokenising integers in a string

Tags: python, string, integer, coordinates, pysal

I have a text file containing coordinates in the form of:

```
[-1.38795678, 54.90352965]
[-3.2115, 55.95530556] 
[0.00315428, 51.50285246]
```

I want to be able to iterate through each coordinate to check which polygon it is in (UK counties in a shapefile), however I am not sure how to tokenise the numbers so that I can have a code along the lines of...

```
for line in coordinates:
    for poly in polygons:
        if points in polygons:
            print(polygons)
            break

        if points not in polygons:
            continue
```

At the moment they are strings but I want to each line to be comprised of the two points so I that the program can try and locate them in a polygon.

Comment: Add the actual format of your file to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could turn the string into a tuple using [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = "[-1.38795678, 54.90352965], [-3.2115, 55.95530556], [0.00315428, 51.50285246]"
>>> seq = literal_eval(s)
>>> print seq[0][1]
54.90352965
```

---

Edit: if the coordinates are on separate lines with no commas,

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = """[-1.38795678, 54.90352965]
[-3.2115, 55.95530556]
[0.00315428, 51.50285246]"""

seq = [literal_eval(line) for line in s.split("\n")]
#or
seq = literal_eval(s.replace("\n", ","))
print seq[0][1]
```

Comment: If I load if the file without reading it I get the error ValueError: malformed node or string: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/JoshuaHawley/sundayCoordinates.txt' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>, or if I do read it and then do seq = literal_eval(s), it sends back the error  File "<unknown>", line 2
    [-3.2115, 55.95530556]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I just took the coordinates from tweets and then want to map densities across the UK, but this part has taken forever to try and work out.

Comment: @JoshuaHawley: it looks like your data file doesn't have commas between lines; try applying `literal_eval` to each line separately.

Comment: The file just has coordinates listed each on a new line [-1.38795678, 54.90352965]
[-3.2115, 55.95530556] [0.00315428, 51.50285246] with no commas between each line

Comment: What happens if you do `seq = literal_eval(file.read().replace("\n", ","))`?

Comment: @Kevin No errors occur when running that, the code you posted before also seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regex which would be considerably faster than ast:

```
import re
with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("[-]?\d+\.\d+")
    data = [list(map(float, r.findall(line))) for line in f]
```

Some timings:

```
In [14]: %%timeit
with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop

In [15]: %%timeit
with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("[-]\d+\.\d+")
    data = [list(map(float, r.findall(line))) for line in f]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 403 µs per loop

 with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("[-]?\d+\.\d+")
    data = [list(map(float, r.findall(line))) for line in f]
   ....:     

In [38]: with open("test.txt") as f:
           data2 = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
   ....:     

In [39]: data == data2
Out[39]: True
```

Just stripping and splitting would be faster again:

```
In [40]: %%timeit
   ....: with open("test.txt") as f:
   ....:     data = [list(map(float, line.strip("[]\n").split(","))) for line in f]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 249 µs per loop
```